# How to display a non-modal, temporary pop-up message in Android?

Tags: android

For an example of what I'm looking for, hit the Home button while you're composing a message in the Gmail app. A little message will pop up at the bottom of the screen for a moment that says "Message saved as Draft."

I can't figure out how to display one of those messages myself, and I'm not sure what to call it so I can't do a search for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html)

Comment: When you create your Toast don't forgot to call the `show()` method to make it appear.

Comment: lol one of the most concise, to the point accepted answers on S/O.  Well done!